# Using callbacks in window.onload

Tags: javascript, callback

I think there is an easy solution for this, but for some reason I am not getting the expected results. My functions look like this:

```
var functionA = function(callback) {
    loadData(fromURL1); // takes some time
    loadData(fromURL2); // takes some time
    callback();         // Should be called AFTER the loadData() functions are finished
}

var myCallBackFunction = function() {
  // this function is called AFTER functionA() is finished
  alert("All my loaded data from URL1 and URL2");
}

window.onload = function() {
   functionA(myCallBackFunction);
}
```

Unfortunately, the `callback()` function above doesn't wait for `loadData()` to finish, and then just calls the alert with empty data.

I read a lot of online examples, but I think I am still missing something obvious.

Comment: Does `loadData` has some async operation inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `loadData()`s are async operations, you can do two things:

Using `$.ajaxComplete()`:

```
var functionA = function(callback) {
    loadData(fromURL1); // takes some time
    loadData(fromURL2); // takes some time
    $.ajaxComplete(function () {
        callback();         // Should be called AFTER the loadData() functions are finished
    });
}
```

Or chaining the functions:

```
var functionA = function(callback) {
    loadData(fromURL1, function () {
       loadData(fromURL2, function () {
           callback();         // Should be called AFTER the loadData() functions are finished
       }); // takes some time
    }); // takes some time
}
```